# How to clear sessionstrage after sometime in javascript

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have this code and it is for login. It keep user as logged in. But I want to clear `sessionStorage` data after 10 min so user will have to log in again

```
var students = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to trigger **sessionStorage** method to logout.

Something like

```
var logoutTimer = setTimeout(function() { sessionStorage.clear(); }, (10 * 60 * 1000));
```

And if for any reason you want to renew session duration, do:

```
clearTimeout(logoutTimer);
logoutTimer = setTimeout(function() { sessionStorage.clear(); }, (10 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: I have couple of sessionstorage in js file . but i want to use this only for user info . What should i do in this case ?